# Avoiding package reinstalls when developing binary module

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging, scikit-build

I'm working on a Python module that contains compiled code. Compiling and installing the module works when using `pip install .` from the directory containing `pyproject.toml` and `setup.py` (I'm not actually sure which combination of these files I need, but it works when both are present at least).

The issue I'm having is that every time I run `pip install .`, `pip` will reinstall cmake and friends:

From the output: `Successfully installed cmake-3.28.3 distro-1.9.0 ninja-1.11.1.1 packaging-23.2 scikit-build-0.17.6 setuptools-69.1.1 wheel-0.42.0`

This has the effect that every time I'm iterating on changes in the source code, I have to sit through this reinstall which takes several seconds each time.

Is there not a way to install *just* my module and none of the dependencies? I've tried `pip install --no-deps .` and `pip install --no-dependencies .` to no avail.

Contents of `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    'setuptools>=42',
    'scikit-build>=0.13',
    'cmake>=3.20',
    'ninja'
]
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
```

`setup.py` just has the name of the package, license, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `pip` sees an `pyproject.toml` file, it automatically enables the ["build isolation"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-isolation) feature[^1].

This means that `pip` will create a "disposable virtual environment" just for building your project and delete this environment once the build is done[^2].

That is why the build dependencies are always re-installed.

To avoid this, you can perform the installation using following steps:

1. Manually install the build dependencies in the same environment where you want your package to be installed (it is a good idea to use virtual environments here).

   - In your example, this means running:

     ```bash
     pip install ninja cmake>=3.20 scikit-build>=0.13
     pip install -U setuptools wheel  # It is good to use the latest version...
     ```
2. Explicitly disable build isolation when installing your project:

   ```bash
   pip install --no-build-isolation .
   ```

   - Note that when using `--no-build-isolation` `pip` will not install any build dependency automatically. That is why we need step 1.
   - This is also why you need to install `wheel` (setuptools automatically adds `wheel` to whatever you specify in `build-system.requires`).

[^1]: Eventually, future versions of `pip` will enable "build isolation" by default, even if you don't have a `pyproject.toml`.

[^2]: The reasoning behind this behaviour is, broadly speaking, to avoid dependency hell and version collisions.

Comment: This works, thank you! And sorry for the late reply.